# Code has but I don't understand where

Tags: php

So I have code what should take item price from bitskins or steamcommunity. It does everything except the price it puts in is 0.

```
<?php
require_once "../config.php";
require_once "../db.php";
$secret ="";
$api = "";
require_once 'GoogleAuthenticator.php';
$ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();
$oneCode = $ga->getCode($secret);
if(!isset($_GET['secret']) || $_GET['secret'] != $config['bot_key_add']){
    die("Access denied");
    return;
}

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$weapon = urlencode($json->weapon);
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=" . $api . "&code=" . $oneCode . "&names=" . $weapon . "&delimiter=!END!";
$steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
$item_price = json_decode($steam_price);
if(empty($item_price) || $item_price->success == false || empty($item_price->price))
{
    $link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=.$weapon";
    $price2 = $item_price->median_price;
    $price2 = str_replace("&#36;" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = str_replace("$" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = round(str_replace(",",".",$price2), 2);
}
else 
{
    $price2 = $item_price->price;
    $price2 = str_replace("&#36;" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = str_replace("$" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = round(str_replace(",",".",$price2), 2);
}
$saveWeapon = $pdo->prepare("");

$saveWeapon->execute([  ":steamId"      => $json->userID,
                        ":classid"      => $json->classid,
                        ":assetid"      => $json->assetid,
                        ":weaponName"   => $json->weapon,
                        ":price"        => $price2,
                        ":float"        => $json->color
]);
?>
```

Here is the bitskins API result if item is in database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm0P0.png
Here is if item is not in database: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZg1r.png

Basically, if item is NOT in database, it should use steam market. I can't find any "Error" codes, but into database it inserts 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's look at what's going on here.

```
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=" . $api . "&code=" . $oneCode . "&names=" . $weapon . "&delimiter=!END!";
$steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
$item_price = json_decode($steam_price);
if(empty($item_price) || $item_price->success == false || empty($item_price->price))
{
    $link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=.$weapon";
    $price2 = $item_price->median_price;
    $price2 = str_replace("&#36;" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = str_replace("$" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = round(str_replace(",",".",$price2), 2);
}
```

You're not getting content from the steamcommunity.com `$link`, and trying to pull a `median_price` from a failed data set.

Try something like this:

```
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=" . $api . "&code=" . $oneCode . "&names=" . $weapon . "&delimiter=!END!";
$steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
$item_price = json_decode($steam_price);
if(empty($item_price) || $item_price->success == false || empty($item_price->price))
{
    $link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=.$weapon";
    // Added
    $steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
    $item_price = json_decode($steam_price);
    // 
    $price2 = $item_price->median_price;
    $price2 = str_replace("&#36;" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = str_replace("$" , "", $price2);
    $price2 = round(str_replace(",",".",$price2), 2);
}
```

Comment: Trying to do that when price is null on bitskins, else it takes price from bitskins or I've done something wrong there :D?

Comment: You use `file_get_contents` to pull from bitskins.com, but if that fails, you're not using `file_get_contents` to pull data from the backup steamcommunity.com

Comment: Umm, Could you please "fix" code for me? Would be super thankful Sir. :)

Comment: Added an example solution.

Comment: Tried your part of code, still entered 0 to database for price.

Comment: You'll have to debug the data set you have. `var_dump($item_price)`

Comment: Like I understood then for bitskins answer is: object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["prices"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["market_hash_name"]=> string(31) "P250 | Supernova (Minimal Wear)" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.29" } } } }

Comment: For steam was is like: object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["lowest_price"]=> string(5) "$0.31" ["volume"]=> string(5) "2,301" ["median_price"]=> string(5) "$0.31" }

Comment: That looks good then. Another problem I see is that you're preparing an empty SQL query: `$saveWeapon = $pdo->prepare("");`

Comment: Another problem. It looks like your price from bitskins is at `$item_price->data->prices[0]->price`, not `$item_price->price`

Comment: Naah, I removed it for no reason if I was posting it here. Btw, if all prices show up, then why the hell it puts 0 into database? :/

Comment: I see. See my last comment about where the price data is located in the bitskins data set.

Comment: Changed that one, still 0 :(. Really interesting actually :D

Comment: Thank You, I will keep trying or maybe someone other will figure it somehow out :).

Comment: I appreciate that you still accepted my answer. Thank you :)